# Select List not populating from ViewModel ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

The select list in one of my views is not populating from the View Model and I can't figure it out.  The other parts of the view model behave as expected. The view is a partial view, if that matters.

Here is the code for the view:

```
 @model Workout_Tracker.ViewModels.AddExerciseViewModel
        <form >
           <div class="individualContainer">
                <label asp-for="ExerciseTypeID"></label>
                <select asp-for="ExerciseTypeID" asp-items="Model.ExercisesTypes">
                </select>
                <label asp-for="Reps"></label>
                <input type="number" asp-for="Reps" />
               </div>
            </form>
```

Here is the View Model:

```
public class AddExerciseViewModel
{
    [Display(Name ="Weight")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="You must enter a weight.")]
    public int Weight { get; set; }

    public int Reps { get; set; }

    //this sets will be used to create the sets in the Exercise_Sets table
    public int Sets { get; set; }

    public int WorkoutID { get; set; }

    public int ExerciseTypeID { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> ExercisesTypes { get; set; }

    public AddExerciseViewModel(IEnumerable<ExerciseType> exercises) {

        ExercisesTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (ExerciseType ex in exercises)
        {
            ExercisesTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = ex.ID.ToString(),
                Text = ex.Name                  
            });
        }
    }

    public AddExerciseViewModel() {

    }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
  public IActionResult WorkoutSelector() {
        IList<ExerciseType> exerciseTypes = context.ExerciseTypes.ToList();

        AddExerciseViewModel addExerciseViewModel1 = new AddExerciseViewModel(exerciseTypes);

        return PartialView("_WorkoutSelector", addExerciseViewModel1);
    }
```

Here is the ExerciseType class:

```
 public class ExerciseType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You are Passing `IEnumerable<ExerciseType>`, ExerciseType is an integer so basically, you are passing an enumerable of numbers and expect to get `ID` and `Name` From it? can you clarify this?

Comment: @Valkyrie That's being passed to the constructor for initializing `ExercisesTypes` property. It doesn't necessarily impact the availability of the model in the view.

Comment: @rdev5 have you read what I said? `ExerciseType` is an integer look at the model itself. how do you get Id and Name from an integer?

Comment: @Valkyrie Sorry, I still don't follow what you're saying. It sounds like you're confusing the property `AddExerciseViewModel.ExerciseType` (which is NOT a type) with some `ExerciseType` class defined elsewhere in this project (that DOES have `ID` and `Name` properties defined) that simply hasn't been included by the OP in these snippets. Furthermore, it doesn't make sense why anyone would go through the trouble of aliasing `int` with a different name like that. The OP clearly knows how to specify `int` when they want an `int` type (there's 5 of them in that `AddExerciseViewModel`).

Comment: He should've added enough information or have proper naming. also answering these types of questions that are not clarified matters enough creates more issues. [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Agreed. @QHafeez, please update your question to include a copy of your `ExerciseType` class for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: @rdev5 I've added the ExerciseType class and changed the int ExerciseType to ExerciseTypeID for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally create `ActionResult` methods in my controllers for the purpose of rendering partials, so I can't directly speak to extenuating circumstances surrounding your MVC pipeline.

Given a traditional ASP.NET MVC project, however, I tend to render my partials not by invoking actions, but as includes within my views using `ViewBag` as a reliable alternative for supplementing additional data to any view/partial in context as necessary.

**~/Views/Workout/Welcome.cshtml**

```
<div>
  <h2>Workout</h2>
  <p>Select your workout below:</p>

  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_WorkoutSelector.cshtml", ViewBag.MyExerciseViewModel);
</div>
```

Then in your controller, just load whatever is you needed in your main action and get rid of the partial action:

```cs
public class WorkoutController : Controller {
  ...

  public ActionResult Welcome() {
    ViewBag.MyExerciseViewModel = new AddExerciseViewModel(context.ExerciseTypes.ToList());

    return View();
  }
}
```

By the way, are you disposing that `DbContext` properly? :)